# Without using a lambda, Is there a shorter way of declaring a Func (delegate) variable in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

So far I know of two different ways to declare a Func variable using a delegate.

**Technique 1**

```
var AddTen = new Func<int, int>(delegate (int input)
{
    return input + 10;
});
```

**Technique 2**

```
Func<int, int> AddTen = delegate (int input)
{
    return input + 10;
};
```

Without using a lambda expression, is there any shorter way to define a Func? It just always seems redundant to me to have to use `Func<int, int>` even though it looks like the type can be inferred from `delegate(int) { return int; }`

Comment: Why don’t you want to use a lambda expression? `new Func<…>(delegate(…))` and `delegate(…)` are virtually deprecated syntaxes as there were superseded by Lambda expressions. That you need to declare Func<…> is probably to differentiate it from Expression<Func<…>> as delegates as well as expressions use the same lambda syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local function vs Lambda C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943117/local-function-vs-lambda-c-sharp-7-0) and [Local functions and SOLID principles C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635937/local-functions-and-solid-principles-c-sharp)

Comment: [Local functions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use a closure.  Then at least the parameter can be omitted.

```cs
int input = 10;
Func<int> AddTen = delegate ()
{
        return input + 10;
};
```

What i don't understand is why not use lambda.  In this case, lambdas are the means of choice to make it shorter.